# How analyze this circuit?

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, diodes

[image]

[image]
I'm working with this circuit.

I don't know how I should analyse in a mathematical way.
I don't know how I should take the analysis of the capacitor in this kind of circuits.
 I have to find the voltage of the capacitor(Vc) without initial conditions (V0)

[image]

Comment: If Vin is 5V peak and diode drop is 0.7V and R1C1=1ms for a 60Hz signal, what do you expect to happen each half cycle?

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist I expect that the signal in the half cycle have a current equal to 0

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist How i should take the capacitor in a mathematical way, i thinking make a Thevenin equevalent with the capacitor in series, but i dont know how a analysis that capacitor because i dont know the initial condition

Comment: As you see the cap voltage rising, the current must increase when the voltage is rising and then change directions and decay thru the 50k resistor. THis is normal rectification.

Comment: 1st trace looks like < 10 Hz, 2nd is 60Hz  . Note the negative Cap decay current droops up back to zero faster.  Error.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist, yes that is true because most of the time the cap will be discharging?

Comment: No I meant your 1st graph has the wrong frequency

Comment: Here's is another simulator you can change in real time or slow motion and change anything with mouse wheel or right click or menu. http://tinyurl.com/y8sen86k

Answer (score 3):

This is a model of full wave rectifier with high source resistance(1kOhm). It has 1uF filtering capacitor and a 50kOhm load. As commented, the charging of the cap is quite fast, only 1ms time constant. The discharging isn't fast due 50ms time constant. You can well assume that the cap charges to the available peak voltage (=AC amplitude - 0,7 volts) AC input dives, but the cap discharges slowly. It starts to charge again when the next rising sine(minus 0,7 volts) meets the decaying voltage of the cap.

Finding where the cap starts to get charged again needs a transcendental equation, which can be solved only iteratively or graphically.  Draw the waveforms and see where the curves meet. Express this as the principle and find more exact numbers with a circuit simulator. It can take the diode into the account more accurately than only assuming 0,7V drop.

The starting transient is different. You must assume initially 0V in the cap. The simulation shows that 4,3V isnt reached in the first half cycle. The simulation also shows that 0,7V drop in the diode is underestimated. There's also some drop in 1kOhm resistors due the 50kOhm load - it's a voltage divider which drops about 2% off.

Comment: What if a chance the cap with a 10uF cap my time constant increse (500ms) and my discharging is more fast that with a 1uf cap?

Comment: @Juanestebanhernandezalvarez increasing C1 to 10uF makes both charging and discharging slower. The initial transient takes more half cycles and the voltage decay between the sine peaks is less than now, I bet it will be about 0,05V. Peak voltage in C1 will be less than now because charging will be substantially slower than now.

Comment: Are you saying that the voltage across the 50k resitor and the 1uf capacitor is the half of the voltage source

Comment: @Juanestebanhernandezalvarez I didn't calculate the peak voltage of C1, I said only it will be less than now and the drop also will be less than now. The simulator calculates it much more accurately than me.

Comment: @Juanestebanhernandezalvarez I calculated the swing limits of the voltage in C1 (=simulated) when C1=10uF. After the initial transient Umin=4V Umax=4,07V.

Comment: Here you can click on the toggle switch, start/**stop** and reset twice , and change anything http://tinyurl.com/y9gnmtgo  drag scope trace window up and recentre schematic